AttributeError: 'KerasHistory' object has no attribute 'layer'
I'm encountering the error "AttributeError: 'KerasHistory' object has no attribute 'layer'" while working with a Keras model.
I'm trying to access layer information, but it seems I'm referencing the wrong object. I tried to change the name layer to operation, but it's not working.
I'm using TensorFlow v2.17.0. This is the code:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, ZeroPadding2D, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, Add, AveragePooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

input_shape = (96, 96, 1)

# Input tensor shape
X_input = Input(input_shape)

# Zero-padding
X = ZeroPadding2D((3,3))(X_input)

# 1 - stage
X = Conv2D(64, (7,7), strides= (2,2), name = 'conv1', kernel_initializer= glorot_uniform(seed = 0))(X)
X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn_conv1')(X)
X = Activation('relu')(X)
X = MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides= (2,2))(X)

# 2 - stage
X = res_block(X, filter= [64,64,256], stage= 2)

# 3 - stage
X = res_block(X, filter= [128,128,512], stage= 3)


# Average Pooling
X = AveragePooling2D((2,2), name = 'Averagea_Pooling')(X)

# Final layer
X = Flatten()(X)
X = Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(X)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = Dense(2048, activation = 'relu')(X)
X = Dropout(0.1)(X)
X = Dense(30, activation = 'relu')(X)


model_1_facialKeyPoints = Model(inputs= X_input, outputs = X)
model_1_facialKeyPoints.summary()

This is the traceback:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-366-fd266d53d661> in <cell line: 34>()
     32 
     33 
---> 34 model_1_facialKeyPoints = Model( inputs= X_input, outputs = X)
     35 model_1_facialKeyPoints.summary()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs(self)
    692       # Check that x is an input tensor.
    693       # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 694 
    695       layer = x._keras_history.layer
    696       if len(layer._inbound_nodes) > 1 or (

AttributeError: 'KerasHistory' object has no attribute 'layer'


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Perhaps https://github.com/naseemap47/FaceRecognition-MTCNN-ArcFace/issues/13 might be able to point you to the right direction?

The problem was fixed when I deleted these two lines:
# 2 - stage
X = res_block(X, filter= [64,64,256], stage= 2)

# 3 - stage
X = res_block(X, filter= [128,128,512], stage= 3)

